# Need help splitting a field with XML-like data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar` column in a table, which contains a string of XML-like data. I say "XML-like" because the string usually gets truncated before I get all of it. I need to pull the `<TransactionID>` and `<EncID>` sections out of the string.

Here is a sample of the beginning of the string I need to parse:

```
<Message>    <TransactionID>1679098</TransactionID>    <EncID>172</EncID>    
    <EncGuid>6028afdc-bc5c-4d3c-b39f-6709ab6ae4d2</EncGuid>
```

I have tried `substring()`, but I can't always identify the endpoints correctly. I think there should be an easy way, since I know the beginning and ending tags around the data I'm after. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a user defined function that uses simple string manipulation for when I need to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBetween]
(
    @Xml    VarChar( MAX ),
    @Start  VarChar( 100 ),
    @End    VarChar( 100 )
)    
RETURNS VARCHAR( 1000 )
AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE @I INT, @J INT

SET @I = CHARINDEX( @Start, @Xml )
SET @J = CHARINDEX( @End, @Xml, @I + LEN( @Start ) )

IF @I > 0 AND @J > @I
BEGIN
    SET @I = @I + LEN( @Start )
    RETURN SUBSTRING( @Xml, @I, @J - @I )
END

RETURN NULL

END
```

Here's how you could use it for your case:

```
SELECT
    dbo.GetBetween(Data, '<TransactionID>', '</TransactionID>') AS TransactionID,
    dbo.GetBetween(Data, '<EncID>', '</EncID>') AS EncID
FROM Your_Table
```

Note that this does not handle escaped characters.  If your XML contains `&amp;` it will be returned as `&amp;`.